# Swift error when added new entity (Core Data)

Tags: swift, core-data

I have just created a new xcode project (Master-datail application) with Core Data.
After I created a new entity (no code added into controllers) I have tried to open the app on iOS simulator and I got this error

> 2015-03-27 17:59:20.882 Blog Reader[2677:301117] CoreData: error:
>   -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/stevik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/29A6C356-8AFA-48BA-B0C0-B6031D760ECE/data/Containers/Data/Application/88603D30-BAED-4F1A-95AB-ADD87C3A469B/Documents/Blog_Reader.sqlite
>   options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error
>   134100.)" UserInfo=0x78f4edd0 {metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Event = <5431c046 d30e7f32 c2cc8099 58add1e7 579ad104 a3aa8fc4 846e97d7 af01cc79>;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "25DE15EE-E903-4544-888B-7326455CF4B3";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2; }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store} with
>   userInfo dictionary {
>       metadata =     {
>           NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
>               Event = <5431c046 d30e7f32 c2cc8099 58add1e7 579ad104 a3aa8fc4 846e97d7 af01cc79>;
>           };
>           NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>           NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
>               ""
>           );
>           NSStoreType = SQLite;
>           NSStoreUUID = "25DE15EE-E903-4544-888B-7326455CF4B3";
>           "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
>       };
>       reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store"; } 2015-03-27 17:59:20.885 Blog
>   Reader[2677:301117] Unresolved error Optional(Error
>   Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN Code=9999 "Failed to initialize the
>   application's saved data" UserInfo=0x78ea27b0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the application's saved
>   data, NSUnderlyingError=0x78f4edf0 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was
>   an error creating or loading the application's saved data.}),
>   Optional([NSLocalizedDescription: Failed to initialize the
>   application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x78f4edd0 {metadata={
>       NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
>           Event = <5431c046 d30e7f32 c2cc8099 58add1e7 579ad104 a3aa8fc4 846e97d7 af01cc79>;
>       };
>       NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
>       NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
>           ""
>       );
>       NSStoreType = SQLite;
>       NSStoreUUID = "25DE15EE-E903-4544-888B-7326455CF4B3";
>       "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2; }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason: There was an error creating or loading the
>   application's saved data.])

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't change the Core Data model and continue to use the same persistent store file unless you implement model migration. Apple provides [considerable documentation on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html). However during app development you can usually just delete the app from the device/simulator and install a new copy. That deletes any existing data, but often that's OK while working on the model.

Comment: This worked for me. I merely deleted the app off the iOS Simulator, and it all started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there is a change in your core data model whether an entity added or any attribute is changed. Delete the application from the simulator and run it again. It won't crash now.

Comment: Deleting the App is not the right solution. How will you do this for the Apps already in the App Store?

Comment: Yes, Deleting is the solution only when you are developing and haven't uploaded an app on appstore. Once it is done, then we need to make a new version of Core Data model and change the attributes in the new model, and upload the new binary on app store.